# port being in use not displayed in netstat output

Tags: centos, netstat

In what scenarios port being used by a process don't show up in `netstat -a` output?

I'm running `jenkins` on my machine. It's listening on port 8080. I'm trying to start another process that tries to bind on same port and it fails with error that port is already in use.

Now when I do `netstat -a | grep 8080`, it doesn't show up in output. After stopping `jenkins` my process successfully bound to 8080. Any clues what happening?

I'm running CentOS.

Comment: Try `netstat -lp`, showing you **processes** that are **listening**.

Comment: Try also `netstat -an | grep 8080`, in case 8080 is in your `/etc/services` file and is being replaced by its symbolic name.

Comment: Another approach would be using  `lsof -i :8080`

Comment: both netstat -an and lsof -i :8080 worked.. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: You port is probably showing up by name rather than number. Uset netstat -an

Answer (score 9):

Just had a similar case on Ubuntu 14.04. Indeed jenkins default port (8080) is mapped to "http-alt" name in /etc/services. You can easily check this with

```
grep 8080 /etc/services
http-alt    8080/tcp    webcache    # WWW caching service
http-alt    8080/udp
```

In addition to netstat you can consider using ss

```
ss -ntl | grep 8080
```

or

```
ss -tl | grep http-alt
```

Answer (score 2):

> In what scenarios port being used by a process don't show up in netstat -a output.

If everything is working correctly, never. As mentioned above, you could have your port number replaced by the service name as listed in `/etc/services`.

Using `netstat -na` ensures service ports are not translated to service names.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue that service was working well on port 443 but there was no 443 port in netstat at all. And finally I found some `iptables` forwarding rule, could list it through

```
iptables -t nat -L -n -v
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use:

```
netstat -tupna
```

This way you won't miss anything.